# The power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{[2+(-1)^n]^n}{3^n} x^n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

The power series **$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{[2+(-1)^n]^n}{3^n} x^n$$** converges.

A. $only\;for\;x=0$

B. $ For\; all\;x\in\mathbb{R}$

C. $Only\;for\;-1<x<1$

D. $Only\;for\;-1<x\leq1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Since
$$
\left|\frac{[2+(-1)^n]^n}{3^n}\right|\leq 1
$$ then the radius of convergence $R$ of your power series is such that $R\geq1$.

Thus, you just have to check the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n \geq0}\frac{[2+(-1)^n]^n}{3^n}
$$ to pick up $C$ or $D$ the case $B$ being easy to discard (take any $x>3$).

Comment: Your hint doesn't preclude B from being true either (although it's not hard to discard it).

Answer (score 0):

$u_n=(\frac{(2+(-1)^n}{3})^n$

By Cauchy Root Test $\frac{1}{R}=\lim \sup u_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim \sup \frac{(2+(-1)^n}{3})=1\implies R=1$

Hence radius of convergence must be $|x|\leq  1\implies -1\leq x\leq 1$ .

Now check the convergence of the series for $x=-1,1$.

Eventually you will end up with $|x|<  1$

Comment: ..is right and radius of converges |x|<1..so right option is 3